# existence of minimizer to the dual problem of a martingale optimal transport type problem

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control, optimal-transportation

Let $\nu$ be a given probability measure on $\mathbb R^2$ and consider function of the following form:

$$L(f)(x_1,x_2)=\sup_{y\,=\,(y_1,y_2)\,\in\, \operatorname{Graph} (f)} \{ x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1 - y_1 y_2\}$$

Consider the following minimization problem:

$$\int_{\mathbb R^2} L(f)(x)\,d\nu \rightarrow \min$$

over all Borel measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb R$. **My question: Does minimizer to this question exist?**

remark: this minimization question is derived as a dual problem to a martingale optimal transport type problem.

Comment: I don't know the answer. All I can tell about that the function being minimized is that it is convex. Explanation: for any fixed x and y_1, the expression in the {...} is linear in f; hence the sup over y_1 is convex; hence the avarage over x is convex.